# What does cast followed by prepositional phrase mean?

Tags: vocabulary

> "Truly, friend; and methinks it must gladden your heart, after your
>   troubles and sojourn in the wilderness," said the townsman, "to find
>   yourself at length in a land where iniquity is searched out and
>   punished in the sight of rulers and people, as here in our godly New
>   England. Yonder woman, Sir, you must know, was the wife of a certain
>   learned man, English by birth, but who had long ago dwelt in
>   Amsterdam, **whence, some good time agone, he was minded to cross over
>   and cast in his lot with us of the Massachusetts**.
>  (Nathaniel
>   Hawthorne, The Scarlet Letter)

The highlighted part doesn’t make any sense to me. Would you parse the sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Hawthorne attempting (not very successfully, to my mind) to write in the language of the 17th century, so you have some archaisms:

> whence = from which place
>   some good time agone = a fairly long time ago
>   he was minded = he took it into his mind, he formed the intention

*Cast in his lot* however is not an archaism but an old metaphor which is still in use. *Cast* here is used in the sense of *throw*, and you will find this in the [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lot?q=lot) under ***throw*** in one's lot with:

> decide to ally oneself closely with and share the fate of (a person or group):
>    *the bourgeoisie had thrown in its lot with the monarchy*

One's *lot* is originally what one has been *al**lot**ted* by fate or Providence, and by extension a token bearing one's name which is entered into a drawing or ***lot**tery*. The metaphor thus signifies that one throws one's lot into the same hat with others, that one joins one's fate to theirs.

> a certain learned man [residing] in Amsterdam, who decided, a while ago, to cross over from that place and, for better or worse, join the Massachusetts Bay colony.